# Unable to Configure Quotas in RHEL6 & CentOS6- quotecheck returns error message

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, fedora, disk-space-utilization

**Unable to Configure Quotas in RHEL6 & CentOS6- quotecheck returns error message**

I've created new partition(/dev/sda6) and mounted it(on /hulk).

Edited /etc/fstab file to give quotas on the partition with following line

```
/dev/sda6   /hulk   ext4   defaults,usrquota,grpquota    0 0
```

and gave the following commands

```
[root@localhost ~]# mount -o remount,rw /hulk

[root@localhost ~]# mount|grep hulk
/dev/sda6 on /hulk type ext4 (rw,usrquota,grpquota)

[root@localhost ~]# cd /hulk

[root@localhost hulk]# ls
lost+found
```

and as i use the quotacheck command, it gives me the following error message

```
[root@localhost hulk]# quotacheck -cug /hulk
quotacheck: Cannot create new quotafile /hulk/aquota.user.new: Permission denied
quotacheck: Cannot initialize IO on new quotafile: Permission denied
quotacheck: Cannot create new quotafile /hulk/aquota.group.new: Permission denied
quotacheck: Cannot initialize IO on new quotafile: Permission denied
```

Comment: What a strange name for a mountpoint. Check `/var/log/audit/audit.log`.

Comment: @Michael Hampton
Yeah! Finally i was able resolve the issue with help of the following link:
 http://www.unix.com/red-hat/176845-user-group-quota-not-working-rhel6-2-ext4-ext3.html

Answer (score 1):

Before you run quota check command you need to disable SELinux. Run the below command:

```
[root@localhost hulk]# setenforce 0
```

now execute quota check command:

```
[root@localhost hulk]# quotacheck -cug /hulk
```